# Modifying private fields with immer.js

Tags: typescript, immer.js

I am trying to change a private field from a method of the same class with immer.js But in this case, I need to access not to `this`, but to the draft instance of same class. This causes an error.

```
import produce from "immer";

export class Test {
    private foo: number = 0;
    bar(foo: number): Test {
        return produce<Test>(this, draft => {
            draft.foo = foo;    // <- TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ bar: (foo: number) => Test; }'.
        })
    }
}
```

Is there some way to use immer.js without turning fields into public?

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same problem and I think I got a better solution:

```
import produce from "immer";

export class Test {
    private foo: number = 0;
    bar(foo: number): Test {
        return produce(this, (draft: this) => {
            draft.foo = foo;
        })
    }
}
```

That seems to satisfy TypeScript with all the strong types benefits :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `draft` to `any` and then access foo untyped.

```js
import produce from "immer";

export class Test {
    private foo: number = 0;
    bar(foo: number): Test {
        return produce<Test>(this, draft => {
            (draft as any).foo = foo;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's solution... But it actually takes away all benefits of typescript. Maybe there are other solutions?

Comment: you could also try to use `Test & { foo: number }` as type.

Comment: This causes TS2546: Property 'foo' has conflicting declarations and is inaccessible in type 'Test & { foo: number; }'.
I can cast to ```Omit<Test, 'foo'> & { foo: number }``` but it's very ugly